# Probability. Solving equation with distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Distribution function is given

$$D(x)= \begin{cases}0, \text{ if } x<0 \\ \frac{x}{5}+\frac{1}{5} \text{ if }  0 \leq x <3 \\ 1, \text{ if } x \geq 3 \end{cases}$$

We need to find $D_1$ - discrete distribution function and $D_2$ - continuous distribution function that equation $$D=p D_1+(1-p)D_2$$ will be correct with chosen $p\in(0,1).$

So I think continuous distribution function should be found $D_2= D'(x)$, but how to find discrete distribution function and find p?

Comment: Are there jumps in the cumulative distribution function? If so, where and how big?

Comment: You should check whether your suggested $D_2$ is a cumulative distribution function or a probability density function

Comment: yes. when x=0 and x=3, jump is 1/5

Comment: and $D_2= 1/5  \text{ when } x \in [0,3) \text{ and }0 \text{ otherwise } $

Comment: So your suggested $D_2$ is not a cumulative distribution function (it is not increasing and does not approach $1$); nor is it a probability density function (its integral is not $1$)

Comment: Yes, I see my suggestion is wrong.. What I have to do then?

Comment: I don't know. If I understand right, D(x)=D

Comment: Maybe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/993851/how-to-express-combined-discrete-continuous-rvs-in-one-pdf) can give you a lead!

Comment: Your $D$ function is a CDF (Cumulative Distribution Function).  You should say it this way. Thus the associated PDF is, by derivation, $\tfrac35 \Pi_{(0,3)}+\tfrac15(\delta_0+\delta_3)$

Comment: From where did you get this?